# Python парсинг страницы

Tags: python, парсер

Имею сайт-цель с которого нужно *спарсить* информацию, но нужные мне блоки **появляются только через 5-20сек после нажатия на кнопку** (button).

Вопросы:

1. Как реализовать "нажатие" на button?
2. Как лучше дождаться появления блока?

Comment: Взять Selenium WebDriver, в нём все нужные функции вроде есть

Comment: Возможно [Using python Requests with javascript pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393231/using-python-requests-with-javascript-pages)? Иначе я бы использовал selenuim.